# Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus unable to configure TransportType

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm currently trying to make use of the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus package following [this Getting Started page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues). I ran into a problem where I would receive the following error:

> **Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException:** 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ErrorCode: ConnectionReset (ServiceCommunicationProblem).

I understand this happens because the port is blocked. To get around this, I created the following:

```
var option = new ServiceBusClientOptions
{
    TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
};

var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, options);
```

As per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-overview#:%7E:text=.NET%20(Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus)).

This solves the problem for the Sender and Receiver code. My problem still occurs with an Azure Function setup to use ServiceBusQueues as its trigger. I saw on that documentation that I can append

> TransportType=AmqpWebSockets;

to the connection string, and it would fix the problem. However that feature doesn't seem to be present in the newer Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus package, only the older Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package.

Is there a way to assign the TransportType for the Service Bus Queue connection string in the Azure Function without downgrading packages? It's currently grabbing the connection string from local.settings.json.

Code for the Azure Function:

```
[Function("ServiceBusQueueTrigger1")]
public static async void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("someQueueName", Connection = "somebus_SERVICEBUS")] string myQueueItem, FunctionContext context)
{
    // some function code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that appending TransportType=AmqpWebSockets; will work to resolve the issue for the Azure Function. It won't work for the Sender/Receiver code since those rely on the NuGet package. The Azure Function does not.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I have a function that does work when deployed. However, if I try to debug (run local) with the --verbose flag, I can see that I am getting a TimeOut error. I know that my local machine at work is blocking AMQP and I must use AmqpWebSockets. I did try appending TransportType=AmqpWebSockets to the connection but still getting errors (therefore the function is not triggered). Also, I verify that my code does work as is when deploying to a different subscription (whose configuration is not blocking ports).

Did you manage to make it work somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions environment does not have the TCP ports blocks and therefore does not require WebSockets. Sending/receiving from/to Azure Functions using Service Bus queues/topics/subscriptions is not impacted by the constrains of other environments you're using. The messages will be flowing to your functions and sent out w/o a problem when the rest of the system (on premises for example) is using web sockets to connect to the namespace.

Comment: I'm havet he same issue at work (where we have Firewall rules). I have a Function with ServiceBusTrigger that does work in Azure but fails (TimeOut error) trying to debug Local. I have to use AmqpWebSockets for sending/receiving from the SBs (e.g. with a ServiceBusTrigger). If I try the same Function code from home against my personal Azure subscription with no problems debugging using the ServiceBusTrigger (with no Firewall restrictions).TransportType=AmqpWebSockets in the connections appear to be ignored. What could cause this issue if it is not a port restriction at the corporate network?

Comment: Is there a fix for this? Appending TransportType=AmqpWebSockets is ignored and therefore unable to debug local (if I deploy, the ServiceBusTrigger has no issues). Note that using AmqpWebSockets to send messages works OK (since the option is set programmatically). The issue is specific to the ServiceBusTrigger. Also, note that the same code does work in another development machine that does not have the ports blocked).