# Azure ServiceBusTopicTrigger - Isolated Function - Managed Identity

Tags: azure, function, dotnet-isolated

I have got Azure Service bus topic trigger created. Not sure why it is not pulling messages off a subscription from a topic. I do have my user role setup in as reader/write in Azure using Visual studio 2022 login to organisations Azure Account.

Using the following versions :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.15.1" />
    
  </ItemGroup>
```

and local.settings.json as

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",    
    "ServiceBusConnectionString__fullyQualifiedNamespace": "xxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net"
  }
}
```

and the function is simply as follows:

```
 [Function(nameof(ServiceBusTrigger))]
 public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("xxxx", "yyyy", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
 {
     _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
     _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
     _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
 }
```

function is started and confirmed messages are in subscription queue:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5413 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.25.3.21264

[2023-10-19T00:32:59.110Z] Found C:\SCM\Poc\functions\ServiceBusTopicDemo\LocalFunctionProj\LocalFunctionProj.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2023-10-19T00:33:01.599Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        ServiceBusTrigger: serviceBusTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-10-19T00:33:05.890Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000C8B5EEE0'.
```

Comment: So the main issue what I understand is it's not pulling messages from the subscription of the topic, even though messages are present in the subscription queue. correct?

Answer (score 0):

***Could you provide more detail about this?***

Is the logging output actually fetching message data? I've done the exact same integration with queues, not topics and it works fine.

I see that your ***ServiceBusConnectionString*** is not the same as defined in your ***local.settings.json***, that will be the case if not set correctly.

Besides that, everything seems okay.

Comment: Bernardo, thanks for the suggestions, I have turned on logging. 
Getting :
 RunOperation encountered an exception and will retry. Exception: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ErrorCode: ConnectionReset (ServiceCommunicationProblem). For troubleshooting information, see https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot.

Comment: Found this: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=servicebus&pivots=programming-language-csharp#local-development-with-identity-based-connections

Comment: This error can be found when the connection string is incorrect or when there are networking issues. Can you validate both are not the case, by ensuring the connection string is exactly the same and that you can ping the host on the connection string?

Comment: Changed the connection string Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXX

has made no difference

Comment: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
[2023-10-19T22:59:20.642Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
[2023-10-19T22:59:20.643Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportStream.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<ReadAsync>b__1(IAsyncResult a)
[2023-10-19T22:59:20.643Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)

Comment: I've checked to see if it is a firewall issue, by running :
tnc <yournamespacename>.servicebus.windows.net -port 5671 got a response back TcpTestSucceeded : True

Comment: I found an [old issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211599/azure-messaging-servicebus-unable-to-configure-transporttype) , 2 years +/-. It looks similar to your issue. Have you tried the suggested solution in there? It seems to be adding `TransportType=AmqpWebSockets;` to the connection string.

Comment: This might be the solution to your prob specially cuz you're getting Amqp socket errors. Please let me know if it helped so I can update the answer :)

Comment: Did add TransportType=AmqpWebSockets; to the end of the connection string. Made no difference. I also created a console application just to check if it was network issues, The console application could pull the messages of queue, It works.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the error you got once you added TransportType=AmqpWebSockets? I can't do it right now, but I'll try this exact integration later on and see if I get the same result.

Comment: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportStream.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<ReadAsync>b__1(IAsyncResult a)   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportStream.

Answer (score 0):

So found out that for this to work need to add to Host.json file, it needs extensions to be added as shown:

```
"extensions": {
    "serviceBus": { "transportType": "amqpWebSockets" },
    "autoCompleteMessages": true
}
```